# A generic error occurred in GDI+ in C#

Tags: c#

I am using a 3rd party control to read barcode from a bitmap file. Below is the code for my method.

```
public void ShowBarcode(IntPtr img)
    {
        int nBarCode;
        SoftekBarcodeLib2.BarcodeReader barcode = new SoftekBarcodeLib2.BarcodeReader();
        barcode.ReadCode39 = 1;
        barcode.ReadNumeric = 1;
        nBarCode = barcode.ScanBarCodeFromBitmap(img);
        for (int i = 1; i <= nBarCode; i++)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(barcode.GetBarString(i));
        }

    }
```

For some reason I am getting the above mentioned error at 
barcode.ScanBarCodeFromBitmap the value of img is 65863972

Comment: Where do you get that parameter `IntPtr img` from???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have received the same error message when dealing with Images in C#. The issue usually revolves around permissions. If the account running the application doesn't have write permissions to where the temporary images are being stored on the file system, you will receive the mentioned error message.

Answer (score 0):

i have face this error twice so i can now understand it 
in the first cast when u upload img it's use stream that u must close it then dispose the object 
in the second case it's them's like doesn't close the object but i faced it because my server have no space to save again 
hope that's help u and other's